# PSP formatted "There are no folders"

Tags: psp

I've never dealt with module gaming peripherals and was confident the process was straightforward, but I made a mistake I need help correcting, please.

I formatted my PlayStation Portable memory card in my Laptop using the "format" option PC side after inserting it into the card reader. After it formatted, when I inserted it into the PSP again, the folders are missing.

How do I format my PSP card to be readable on the PSP again?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, isn't that what formatting does essentially?  When you format a hard drive, it is going to remove everything on it.  I'm also going to guess that since you used your laptop instead of [the built in tools on the PSP to format it](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/7999/sony-psp-go-psp-how-to-completely-wipe-device-and-memory-card-and-remove-psn-id/), that the PC went and wiped it completely where as the PSP would know how exactly it should be formatted.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yes, that is how formatting works. I don't know *why* you would want to do that, but when you format from a pc, it wipes all data. I don't know about a format through the psp, but that should do as you say.

Comment: People try to do it this way for a couple of reasons. None of them very luminous, but usually this happens to people who try and hack their PSP.

Comment: What model PSP, was it the PSP or SD card you formatted, what option did you use to format the PSP / SD card, and what did you insert to discover your problem? Please clarify in your question so I may better assist you.

Comment: What option did I use to format I? Here

Comment: I used a card reader

Comment: I used a card reader and I inserted a it to a isb port using my laptop

Comment: I opened my laptop's documents folser then  I  clicked "removable disk and clicked Format "    then it was formatted  "I removed my  memory stick from the card reader then later   I inserted it again to the laptop's usb Port  then there "All EMPTY"

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know a PSP could do that is I'm a noob at these peripherals

Comment: I formatted my PSP

Comment: I don't even know hack I just wanted to format the memory stick so u can download new games all over again "weird right"

Comment: The memory stick I formatted  is s Sony  memory stick pro Hg duo 8gb

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you expected to happen when you clicked format.  That might help everyone understand what your question is.  Basically right now it feels like you're telling us that you put bread in a toaster and were surprised to get toast, so it's not really clear what the issue is.

Comment: OK, but you'll need to edit your question. I've made some suggestions for you to peer review and approve or decline so that you can get an answer that's helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you've inserted the PSP Memory Stick DUO into your laptop, formatted the card and then upon reinsertion to the PSP, get a blank card. This can happen for a number of reasons.

I suggest following steps from [here](http://www.methodshop.com/gadgets/tutorials/pspformatstick/index.shtml) first to see if you can reformat from the device itself. Reformatting from the device will apply specific structure and settings on the card from the device without additional steps.

With the memory stick in the PSP, make sure that the memory card supports MagicGate by going to Music, Video, or Games on the XMB and pressing the *triangle* button. There, it will display if Magic Gate is supported.

You'll need to ensure the card was formatted in FAT32 **not** NTFS. NTFS may be required to move a movie from the PC to PSP, but the PSP won't read NTFS format.

Use the Sony Memory Stick formatter software to format your memory stick and it should be readable by your PSP, onlbtained [here](https://esupport.sony.com/p/swu-download.pl?upd_id=2860).

When you get back to usability, make sure you have the [latest firmware update](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/system-updates/psp/) from Sony for your PSP.